# Why did Wordpress overwrite my custom TwentyTwelve Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Do the standard TwentyTweleve, TwentyThriteen and TwentyFourteen Wordpress themes update automatically? I had some pretty heavy customizations in the TwentyTwelve Wordpress theme that were overwritten out of now where. Did not update Wordpress to a later version.

Do those themes update automatically? If I rename the folder to "MyCustomTheme" will I prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, **anytime you preform a core update on any application, you should always do a backup of your system in its' current state including any databases you may have in place.**

Beyond that, you can prevent WordPress from overwriting any customization to the default themes by simply renaming that theme's folder.

**However,** I also recommend looking into starter themes for WordPress such as [Underscores](http://underscores.me/) and [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/) instead of starting with one of the built in themes.

Comment: as said by pieter goosen , used child theme for the solution , so that if there is any update in original theme u can do update easily .. else u cant do update.

Comment: Child themes: yes it is true that child themes are better if you are just trying to modify one of the built in themes. however, most people who are editing the built in themes are just trying to make there own theme but don't know the system well enough to make it from scratch. In this case, using a started theme is better. If they were trying to edit a large or complex framework theme (like Genesis) I would have said use a child theme.

Comment: Agreed, a default template theme was needed as a base so twentytwelve was take advantage of, I was not aware of Underscores or Bones so this great information for the future.

Nick, you are sure by renaming the theme, I will prevent further updates correct?

Comment: @BrianOgden When WordPress updates, it is just overwriting the that themes folder, so just renaming the folder is enough to prevent it from being overwritten. However, it is also a good idea to rename the theme in the `style.css` file so there isn't any confusion in the dashboard. Also, there are a bunch of starter themes for WordPress, but Underscores and Bones are just the most popular.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I never update core plugins or themes so I can always update. It just wasn't an issue with this scenario and I didn't alter the Twenty Twelve them anyways, another developer did that my client got fed up with.

Comment: No problem, but I must say that updates are often important. Not just for new features, but security patches too. The trick is simply not to put yourself in a position where updating is hard or troublesome. Beyond that, I am glad I could help =)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a lot of bull.

Here is what happens and what you **should** do

First of all, **NEVER** make any changes to any core file/plugin or theme, except when you are the author of that particular theme/plugin. The most obvious reason is the one that you've seen now, every change gets overwritten on updates. The core themes automaticaaly updates with core update.

The solution, create a child theme. The bundled themes are excellent for child themes. Child themes are really easy to create, 5minute max. You can modify the parent theme as you like, and the great thing is, it never gets updated or overwritten on core updates. You are the only one that can alter your child theme or update it as you wish.

There are many tutorials out there on child themes, even the codex have a page dedicated page to creating a child theme. Read that, it should help you out a lot.

Comment: Well that is great and I ALWAYS follow the practice of not editing a core plugin/theme. But I didn't originally alter the TwentyTwelve theme, that was done by another development team my client dropped because he is tired of delays. So for now, I copied the theme and renamed it. Is renaming the theme in a different folder going to prevent TwentyTwelve updates?

Comment: Yes it is good practice to avoid overwriting built-in themes/plugins. But not every developer is aware of child themes, and by the time they hear about child themes, a lot of work has already gone into customizing the built in themes, and it would essentially be a wasted effort to change it to a child theme when a simple directory rename will do the trick. However, I do believe that once a developer is aware of child themes, they should be using them and not modifying the originals.

Comment: Well, that depends on what **you** want to achieve. You can rename the twenty twelve theme to prevent updates, but still not good practice. Why don't you create a theme from scratch based on the twenty twelve theme. I did that with the twenty fourteen theme, and it works great.

Comment: Yes that is true, but it still comes back to the point of why the average developer is editing the built in theme. In **most** cases, it is just a starting point for a theme that needs to look and work completely differently. That being said, the built in themes are pretty plain and only use minimal features; so if someone is going to create a child theme, they will usually use one of the more robust themes as a base. Based on that statistic, it makes more sense to suggest a starter theme rather than a child theme.